# how can I get a simpler data

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have matchCollection.
And I need group index 1. 
Now I take out the data from a large number of casts, I would like to avoid it.

example: startTag = `<a>`, endTag = `</a>`
Html = `<a>texttexttext</a>`.

I need get "texttexttext" with out `<a>` and `</a>`

```
 var regex = new Regex(startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 var matchCollection = regex.Matches(html);
 foreach (var item in matchCollection)
 {

      string temp = ((Match)(((Group)(item)).Captures.SyncRoot)).Groups[1].Value;
 }
```

Comment: You know that regex and HTML/XML make bad friends, yes?

Comment: @Marc Gravell, why? I do not know how else to

Comment: Why are ou using SyncRoot here?

Comment: Why is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags - HTML agility pack might be better

Comment: You simply must not parse html with regex. It will call forth the old gods and bring madness and destruction upon mankind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capture group. You might also want to use a named group. Notice the parentheses I added to regex.

```
        var html = "<a>xx yyy</a>   <a>bbb cccc</a>";
        var startTag = "<a>";
        var endTag = "</a>";
        var regex = new Regex(startTag + "((.*?))" + endTag, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var matchCollection = regex.Matches(html);
        foreach (Match item in matchCollection)
        {
            var data = item.Groups[1];
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
```

This is even a little nicer, because a named group is a little easier to grab.

```
        var html = "<a>xx yyy</a>   <a>bbb cccc</a>";
        var startTag = "<a>";
        var endTag = "</a>";
        var regex = new Regex(startTag + "(?<txt>(.*?))" + endTag, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var matchCollection = regex.Matches(html);
        foreach (Match item in matchCollection)
        {
            var data = item.Groups["txt"];
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
```

Comment: That I happen to razobratsya parser could not, in this is a good working variaant.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML instead of regex for [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

So to apply it to your example with finding all anchor text inside an HTML document:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string html = "";
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            html = client.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com");
        }

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
        {
            // Will print all text contained inside all anchors 
            // on http://stackoverflow.com
            Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.